# Override background-color using `!important`

Tags: javascript, css

How do I override class background color?
Tried `!important` but not working, the text is still yellow.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.myclass {
  background-color: yellow ;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="myclass" background-color="red !important">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want use inline styles (not good), you should use `style` attribute on html elements and in any way of using css you should use colon `:` instead of `=` for giving value to properties, try this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .myclass {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p class="myclass" style="background-color:red !important;">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put inline css in the `style` attribute like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.myclass {
  background-color: yellow ;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="myclass" style="background-color: red !important;">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention style.

```
<p class="myclass" style="background-color:red !important;">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
```